# How to move git branch up tree (reverse rebase)

Tags: git, branch, git-rebase

Say I have a series of commits that looks like this:

```
h {master}
^
f g {branch1}
^ ^
d e
^/
c
^
b
^
a
```

I know I can move the branch1 to the end of the tree via rebase, so it would look like this: `d->f->h->e->g`.

But, is there any way I can move the branch UP the tree, so it looks like this?

```
h {master}
^
f
^
d g {branch1}
^ ^
c e
^/
b
^
a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While being on `branch1`, run `git rebase --onto b c branch1`. This should do the job.

Comment: It wouldn't work, I have tested. b is an ancestor of c and branch1 so nothing would happen with a simple rebase to b.

Comment: It will work, that's the way rebase is meant to work. If you have already test something using `--onto`, you should double check which command you ran. If you want to convince yourself, go to official doc (https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) and search for `git rebase --onto master topicA topicB`

Comment: I tested it again and this time it works well, maybe I misspelled SHA! the first time. +1 for thanks. Then I noticed what is different between your solution and mine, you mean **squash** `c` to `e` while I mean **remove** c from history. Maybe I misunderstood it.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it is **removing c from branch1** rather than the usual meaning of rebase. You can do it with interactive mode of `rebase`

```
git rebase -i b<SHA1>
```

remove the line of `pick c<SHA1>` and complete.

Comment: +1 because this is a good idea, although I think --onto is the officially correct solution that does the same thing.

Comment: @Benubird I should admit not exactly same though, please refer to my comment in Guillaume Darmont's answer, in case. The real identity is `squash c<SHA1>` in interactive mode rather than remove it. My previous approach will discard modification which `c` introduced.

Comment: yes, removing the line is right. I'm trying to remove `c` from branch1, not squash it, and both answers do that.